# ROS Answers SE migration: Ros Networking

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My setup:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=alpa
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://alpha:11311

export ROS_HOSTNAME=betha
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://alpha:11311
```

I ran  **turtlesim_node** on the first machine and the **turtle_teleop_key** on the second machine. i have already launch the roscore on the Master machine, the turtlesim and turtle_teleop_key launch well but i dont have the remote when I tooch the key to move the turtle.

someone has an idea ?

thanks

---

Edit: any hostname is attach at one Ip adress different. when i ping `r2d2` on `c3po` i have the exchange. The connection between the 2 ros is good because I can start the master and the processes start on each pc starts without error but not the control

i want to do with the teleop_key

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=r2d2 
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://c3po:11311.
```

I run turtlesim in this machine

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=c3po 
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://c3po:11311
```

in this one I ran firts `roscore` and `turtle_teleop_key`, all ran well but no romote of turtlesim by `turtle_teleop_key`.

help please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262294/ros-networking/) by [polin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30488/polin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [wiki/ROS/MultipleMachines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines).

You only run a single master, so both `ROS_MASTER_URI` variables should point to the same IP (ie: the one running your `roscore`).

Additionally: the value of `ROS_HOSTNAME` is used by ROS nodes to identify who is 'talking' to them. But `localhost` is a special hostname, that will (should?) always resolve to the local machine (at `127.0.0.1`). It is therefore not usable to configure a distributed (ie: networked) ROS nodegraph.

Make sure to use either globally resolvable hostnames *or* don't set `ROS_HOSTNAME`, but set `ROS_IP` to the IP of the network interface that you use to connect both computers to the same network.

---

Edit: the first version of your question used `localhost` everywhere, the second `c3po` and `r2d2` and your last version now uses `alpha` and `betha`. Can you confirm that those hostnames actually resolve to IPs? The values you set for `ROS_HOSTNAME` have to actually be existing hosts on your network, you cannot just make something up.

On `alpha`, what is the output of `ping betha` (or on `c3po`, what is the output of `r2d2`)?

---

> ```
> export ROS_HOSTNAME=r2d2
> ```

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://c3po:11311
```

Edit 2: just making sure: you are `export`ing those variables in all terminals that you start ROS programs in? Or do you have those `export` lines added to your `.bashrc`?

If you haven't, add the `export` lines to your `.bashrc` on both machines (for now, at least). Close all terminals.

Now on `c3po`:

- open a new terminal: start `roscore` in it
- open a new terminal: run the following:

  ```
   rostopic pub -r1 /chatter std_msgs/String "something"
  ```

Now on `r2d2`:

- open a new terminal: run the following:

  ```
   rostopic echo /chatter
  ```

you should now see `rostopic` printing "something" once per second.

To make sure everything us working, do the reverse (so start `rostopic pub -r1 ..` on `r2d2` and `rostopic echo ..` on `c3po`).

If you don't get any output from `rostopic echo ..` on `r2d2`, your network setup is not correct. In that case, try a `rosnode ping /rosout` on `r2d2`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [polin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30488/polin/) on 2017-05-23**:
See the change

- export ROS_HOSTNAME=r2d2 export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://c3po:11311. I run turtlesim in this machine
- export ROS_HOSTNAME=c3po export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://c3po:11311 in this on I ran roscore and turtle_teleop_key , all ran well but no romote of turtlesim by turtle_teleop_ke

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-23**:
Please edit (*add*, not *overwrite*) your original question with this new information. The comments are not really suited for these things.

Also: please clarify what you mean with "all ran well".